# Connecting to mongodb through the browser?

Tags: mongodb

Im reading the mongodb guide, but I dont get this:

```
mongodb://fred:foobar@localhost
```

It says I can connect to the mongodb through web browser.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. Safari/Firefox can't recognize the mongodb protocol.

And why should I do it?

Isn't the mongodb server just for connecting through the command line?

And what is the difference between port 27017 and 28017?

Should I connect through http or mongodb protocol?

Comment: I use the Robot 3T to that purpose: https://studio3t.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you start mongod (the MongoDB daemon), it starts listening on two ports by default.

1. **27017**: the default port accessed by the various MongoDB drivers.
2. **28017**: a port that handles HTTP requests and provides some general monitoring.

What you've listed `mongodb://fred:foobar@localhost` actually represents this: `mongodb://fred:foobar@localhost:27017` and this is the access protocol for MongoDB drivers.

The other "thing" you're seeing is port 28017. This is (by default) simply an overview of what's happening with the `mongod` instance on that server. Requests made from a web browser to this port will show an HTML output of the server overview.

If you start `mongod` with a different port number (*i.e.: 7777*), the "monitor" port will always be 1000 higher (*i.e.: 8777*).

If you want some advanced features like the ability to query via the web browser, you can start `mongod` with the `--rest` switch. You will then be able to run certain queries with a simple http get request[link text](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) (`http://localhost:8777/mydb/mycollection/?filter_a=1`).

If you're using language-specific MongoDB drivers (like most people will). Then you'll find that you'll have "connection strings" of the form `mongodb://user:pwd@host:port/`. These are similar in purpose to the usual connection strings you're used to for other Database products.

Comment: is it recommended to use a language specific MongoDB driver? I want develop an interface to mongoDB on a new language. I have 2 options: either build on an existing API such as C or C++, or create from scratch using curl and webserver?

Comment: Note that there are both official drivers (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) and unofficial drivers (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/community-supported-drivers/). There's a MongoDB driver for all major language of the last 10 years, so unless you're writing this in COBOL or APL, you should be covered. And yes it recommended because writing a driver is a lot of detailed work with a high chance of failure.

Comment: @RockScience, I would add an exception for "doing something very specific". If you only need some small subset of MongoDB features then maybe you can get some performance boost from "self-written" drivers. But if that's your goal, you could probably get a performance boost using something other than MongoDB.

Comment: there is no library for R. (actually there are 2 packages, one is not maintained and one is very incomplete: doesnt support database update). Which is quite surprising as R is a very commun language nowadays.

Comment: Might be worth forking and updating?

Answer (score 2):

Increment by one thousand (28017), and use HTTP, not mongodb.

Note that this will "connect" you to the mongodb process, but it's not like phpMyAdmin or anything.

Comment: From the guide "mongodb://localhost,localhost:27018,localhost:27019". Why are they using mongodb protocol?

Comment: @ajsie: No idea, but for the web interface that is incorrect.