# Is it possible to save a file to MongoDB directly from the browser?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to save a file to MongoDB directly from the browser or do I have to upload the file to some directory on the server first, and then insert the file into MongoDB on the server side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595440/connecting-to-mongodb-through-the-browser?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can not directly talk to MongoDB. So the answer is clear and obvious: no.
You need to implement a web-gateway in between.

Answer (score 0):

On a stock installation of MongoDB, there is no REST interface for queries; you'll have to use your existing web app (your best bet for this type of situation), or add an interface layer around MongoDB.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface# and http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb for more info about file storage and interacting with MongoDB via REST.