# android connect to localhost mongodb

Tags: android, mongodb

I try to connect and query from mongodb from my localhost mongodb server.

In my android app, I include mongo-2.10.1 driver, and the code are:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = null;
try {
  mongoClient = new MongoClient("192.168.1.101", 27017);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("gaitroid_database");

DB db = mongoClient.getDB("gaitroid_database");
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("username", username);
DBCursor cursor = patients.find(searchQuery);
```

where 192.168.1.101 is the IPv4 address shared with my computer and android phone.
Anyone can tell me was wrong or the correct way to connect? Thank you!!

LogCat error:

```
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459): java.lang.IllegalStateException: _out shouldn't be null
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:110)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:286)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:412)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.gaitroid.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:49)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-18 00:31:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31459):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Mongo shell:

```
c:\mongodb\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
> show dbs
gaitroid_database       0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
```

>

Comment: Try to use other Thread or AsyncTask for such things(network operation) maybe mongodb lib intearnally "eat" NetworkOnMainThreadException and thats yore getting this error... But this is only bling guessing

Comment: Are you sure your MongoDB is accessible? Try to access it from the phones web browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595440/connecting-to-mongodb-through-the-browser also be sure that the port you are using is not blocked by the firewall.