# Can Javascript natively connect to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, html

I am trying to find if a Javascript script/file (filename.js) that is loaded when accessing a webpage (via `<script src=""> </script>`) can natively connect to a MongoDB instance (running on the same server) and query for some aggregate data.

I am then trying to pass the aggregate query data (which returns as a list of documents in Mongo) to [Morris Charts](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/), so it will display in a bar chart on the webpage.

The only things I have been able to find talk about using Node.js (which I do not want to do), or loading a `.js` file in the Mongo shell.

Can someone tell me if a Javascript file can make a connection to Mongo? If not, is there a way to make the query in Python (running the Flask framework) and pass that data to the Javascript file?

I have tested the following code, but it was unsuccessful (no charts display at all):

```
var con = new Mongo();
var db = conn.getDB("DBName");
var query = db.Collection.aggregate(<aggregate query here>);

Morris.Bar({
element: 'bar-chart',
data: query,
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y'],
labels: ['label'],
hideHover: 'auto',
resize: true
});
```

I also tested the following code, which did work:

```
var dataset = [
{x: '1', y: 10},
{x: '2', y: 20},
{x: '3', y: 40}
];

Morris.Bar({
element: 'bar-chart',
data: dataset,
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y'],
labels: ['label'],
hideHover: 'auto',
resize: true
});
```

Comment: To use Python to access MongoDB: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/

Comment: Do you literally have "<aggregate query here>"? Can you get the data from a prompt?

Comment: @doctorlove I have my actual query that pulls information from Mongo there.  I can't post the actual query there, but when I execute the query in a Mongo shell I get the data I want to display in the Morris charts.

Comment: How about [RESTful Mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595440/connecting-to-mongodb-through-the-browser)

Comment: typically, you wouldn't want to open Mongo (or a database) up directly to your javascript in a browser for security reasons.  Typically, only the web server or application server would have access to the database on a network level.  Does this not apply in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a direct connection to Mongo from a javascript file in client browser
Think of the security breach if that was the case.
I think the best solution for your problem is to send an Ajax request to the server and get the aggregated data as  Json  and parse it and give input to the chart api.

Comment: Do you know of any decent tutorials/intro's on Ajax to perform that type of operation?  I am not familiar with Ajax.

Comment: @SirCobalt Literally just Google "How to AJAX". Plenty of good tutorials. Just keep in mind, AJAX is not what connects to the DB. AJAX is used to load another web page in the background of an already loaded web page. So your AJAX call page would be to a web page that would handle the connection for you (eg. PHP, ASP.NET)

Comment: @Koodlee I'm looking into AJAX and it does seem the right way to go. Being a Network Engineer trying to fill a gap in procedure, a lot of these languages are new to me. The feedback is appreciated.