# Read JSON from Mongodb client side with pure javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to read JSON from a document in a Mongodb collection using only client-side inline javascript/jquery? I don't know much about the subject so I would appreciate any literature/resources you could point me towards. This might be totally impossible, I'm just looking for pointers. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330905/can-javascript-natively-connect-to-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to get the the info from the server-side

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "your url",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more please? Can this script be run client side? Does it rely on managing a same origin policy? What form does the response come in?

Comment: You can run this script on client side if you wrap with you <script></script> but you should do it on .js file,   and the response you get from the server side is a JSON converted to array.  the word "res" you see above is the response