# Cannot connect to MongoDB from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make a connection to my MongoDB database but I get the following error message:

```
AssertionError
actual: null
expected: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at isUndefined (<anonymous>:2748:21) at Object.exports.deprecate (<anonymous>:2330:7) at <anonymous>:2332:22 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41 at <anonymous>:2332:41
generatedMessage: true
message: "null == [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]"
name: "AssertionError"
operator: "=="
stack: "AssertionError: null == [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]↵    at <anonymous>:73719:10↵    at err (<anonymous>:71483:14)↵    at executeCallback (<anonymous>:71472:25)↵    at executeOperation (<anonymous>:71490:7)↵    at MongoClient.connect (<anonymous>:64885:10)↵    at Object.274.assert (<anonymous>:73718:8)↵    at o (<anonymous>:1:265)↵    at r (<anonymous>:1:431)↵    at <anonymous>:1:460↵    at m (http://localhost/mudfeval-mobile/public/src/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:711)"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ AssertionError(options)
__proto__: Object
```

Maybe you would reprobate me for not having checked and reused previous topics. But despite the similarity of the problem, none of them matches with my case.

For the connection, I am following this tutorial: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/ (look at "Connect to MongoDB"):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = "mongodb://secretoes:thatstotallysecret@mudfeval-shard-00-00-uxnqk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,mudfeval-shard-00-01-uxnqk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,mudfeval-shard-00-02-uxnqk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=mudfeval-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true";;

// Database Name
const dbName = 'moodle';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

Once said that, could somebody help me? I cannot find out anything anywhere. I am puzzled.

=============
**UPDATE (11/8/2018 - 01:11 pm UTC+1)**

If I run the script through console, I get no problem. However I receive a deprecation warning that asked me to use the new parser.

So, when I run it on web browser after those changes, the error message is the following:

```
VM188:1932 Uncaught 
AssertionError {name: "AssertionError", actual: null, expected: TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function
    at parseConnectionString (<anonymous>:52229:75)
    at …, operator: "==", message: "null == [TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function]", …}
actual: null
expected: TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function at parseConnectionString (<anonymous>:52229:75) at connect (<anonymous>:68112:3) at connectOp (<anonymous>:68216:3) at executeOperation (<anonymous>:71488:24) at MongoClient.connect (<anonymous>:64885:10) at Object.274.assert (<anonymous>:73718:8) at o (<anonymous>:1:265) at r (<anonymous>:1:431) at <anonymous>:1:460 at m (http://localhost/mudfeval-mobile/public/src/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:711)
generatedMessage: true
message: "null == [TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function]"
name: "AssertionError"
operator: "=="
stack: "AssertionError: null == [TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function]↵    at <anonymous>:73719:10↵    at err (<anonymous>:71483:14)↵    at executeCallback (<anonymous>:71472:25)↵    at executeOperation (<anonymous>:71490:7)↵    at MongoClient.connect (<anonymous>:64885:10)↵    at Object.274.assert (<anonymous>:73718:8)↵    at o (<anonymous>:1:265)↵    at r (<anonymous>:1:431)↵    at <anonymous>:1:460↵    at m (http://localhost/mudfeval-mobile/public/src/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:711)"
__proto__: Error
```

Is it because of browserify?

Comment: This could be because you create a new connection every time when you need it. If this is the case, the problem isn't with the code what you pasted (it seems fine to me), but the number of the times when you import it from your routes for example. The solution would be to initiate one connection only and share it across the whole server.

Comment: It cannot be the case because sometimes I have created PHP applications that call different times the correspondant functions to connect to the server sucessfully, @lependu.

Comment: What node version are you using? Are you seeing Connected successfully to server being logged or do you get the error on first connect try?

Comment: According to npm, 3.10.10 version, @n32303. On the other hand I get the error on first connect attempt.

Comment: That's probably npm version. Can you try executing 'node -v' ?

Comment: And try updating node version to node 10 (LTS)

Comment: That is v6.11.2, @n32303. Sorry for lapsus.

Comment: Probably not issue with version, but node 6 is older version, Node version 10 is currently LTS, can you try with that one? Also do you have latest version of mongodb package installed?

Comment: Yes, that's "mongodb": "^3.1.8". Besides I am already downloading Node 10 installer.

Comment: I've already updated MongoDB but problems remain, @n32303. Anyway I have updated the header message to give more info regarding the error.

Comment: I am using "browserify" because I want to run that in a web app

Comment: If I do not run the scripts from the webbrowser I do not get any problem -though I receive the following deprecation warning: _'DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true }_

Comment: So, when I set that, the error message is that _qs.unescape is not a function_

Comment: Did I get it right that you try to connect directly to a MongoDB via web browser?

Comment: @CiconiaGrullera you should not in any case try to connect to database via web browser. Instead, you should implement a backend service that is deployed on a server and exposes some sort of API and connects to mongo. From webbrowser, you then communicate with that service over that API.

Comment: Got it. I understand I cannot invoke it through web browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your update I get that you try to connect directly to a MongoDB via web browser by using Browserify.

I do not think that this will work. A connection to MongoDB is done by a TCP connection, which will not be available from your browser, or to be more precise: I highly doubt that is that simple as using `Browserify` and everything is OK. There is probably no driver to connect to MongoDB in your browser or many other prerequisites which certainly are not all in my mind.

See this for a suitable answer: [Connecting to mongodb through the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595440/connecting-to-mongodb-through-the-browser)

Comment: Got it. I understand I cannot invoke it through web browser. Thanks.